# Add Page without using Visual Studio in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

Is there any way to create a new page in MAUI without using Visual Studio?
I tried to find the official documentation but could not find it.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? The official documentation won't tell you how to do it without Visual Studio, because MAUI comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: @ewerspej I use tmux + vim for my everyday coding and don't want to start up visual studio just to add pages.

Comment: I don't think there's a CLI command for this. AFAIK, Visual Studio uses template files for that. You would need to create a script and generate the files yourself, maybe by using the existing templates installed with VS. Generally, the structure of a `ContentPage` or `ContentView` is simple enough to generate with a script - with or without using a template.

Comment: MAUI is just C#.  Use any text editor

Comment: I can recommend MS-DOS Editor. At version 2.0, you can edit more than one file (your XAML and XAML.CS file) at the same time, while the old version supports only single file. It is fast, lightweight and has mouse support. You will have to also make sure that those pages are compiled, so you need to add them to your project with specific build actions. (You can edit 9 files at once, so you can do it at the same time).

Comment: @BoKuToTsuZenU VS does, much much more, than just adding pages. The more you delve into MAUI, the more and more things you need to do at hand. And the most important thing - tomorrow when something changes. All your hard work will be gone. And you will have to start doing it again. There are whole teams of programmers, that do this work for you. Use their work, and focus on your own. (The alternative is what I said earlier)